# Python decorator with typing package

Tags: python, types

I'm not sure how to have specific type for decorator's inner function which takes in a function of type `Callable[..., Any]`. I have the following example written:

```
from typing import Callable, Any
from threading import Thread, Lock

def synchronized(function: Callable[..., Any]):
    lock = Lock()

    def innerFunction( -- whatAreTheParametersWithTypeHere -- ):
        lock.acquire()
        function( -- whatAreTheParametersWithTypeHere -- )
        lock.release()
    
    return innerFunction

class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__value: int = 0

    @synchronized
    def threadFunc(self):
        self.__value = 0

        for _ in range(10000000):
            self.__value += 1

        print(self.__value)

def main():
    testObj = Test()

    for _ in range(100):
        thread = Thread(target=testObj.threadFunc, args=())
        thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `innerFunction` is going to replace the function received as an argument, you can't say anything more than what you already know about `function`: it's a callable that takes arbitrary arguments and could return anything.

```
def synchronized(function: Callable[..., Any]):
    lock = Lock()

    def innerFunction(*args, **kwargs):
        lock.acquire()
        function(*args, **kwargs)
        lock.release()
    
    return innerFunction
```

That said, this isn't a useful decorator. Every decorated function will create and use its own private lock, protecting it from nothing, as no other function can try (and fail) to acquire the lock being held by the decorated function.

Comment: I know that it will not work, I just wanted to know how to have arguments passed to `innerFunction` properly. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: `innerFunction` will receive whatever arguments you give it when you call, for example, `threadFunc`. It doesn't know or care what will be received (since it doesn't do anything except pass them on to the original function), so you just have to be prepared to accept anything.